# Convert &#xC3;&#xA4; to Umlaut

Tags: php, xpath, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am parsing a Document via xpath and fetch info from a metatag.
I am passing thsi string through `utf8_decode( $metadesc )` but still get no normal Umlauts. The Document is UTF-8.

I want to convert `&#xC3;&#xA4` to `ä`.

I am debugging via the console in firebug and write the data also into a DB.
In both cases, I get the same result.
For text inside Div's it works. Only that one of the metatag is wrong.

Many Thanks

Comment: Would you please provide a minimal working example of your code, including the output?  When you say you are getting no umlauts, do you mean in the web page you are generating with your php script?  How are you inspecting the output?

Comment: @cxw Please have alook at my edit.

Comment: `$str = '&#xC3;&#xA4;';  echo html_entity_decode($str); // Ã¤`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's true that xC3A4 is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character xE4 which is ä. But in XML, the sequence  `&#xC3;&#xA4;` represents something quite different: it represents "capital A with tilde" followed by "currency sign" (that is, Ã¤). If you use an XML parser, you will see these two characters, and you won't get any indication that they started life as hex character references.

If possible, you should try and fix the program that generated this incorrect encoding of the character: that's much better than trying to repair the damage later.

If you do want to do it by a "repair" operation, you need to take into account that the sequence Ã¤ might actually represent the two characters that XML says it represents: how will you tell the difference? I don't know any PHP, but basically the way to do it is to extract the hex value xC3A4 and then put this through UTF-8 decoding.